# Ubuntu VM gets "destination host unreachable" for network, yet host is able to reach network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, routing, proxmox

I'll try to keep this short. I've got two Proxmox nodes at two separate sites, each behind a pfSense instance with a Wireguard site-to-site tunnel. Each Proxmox machine has (among others) an Ubuntu VM.

[image]

The Proxmox hosts can ping one another, but the Ubuntu VMs can't ping each other or the hosts on the opposing side of the tunnel. However, the Ubuntu machines each *can* ping the pfSense instance on the other side of the tunnel.

So, for example, 172.20.0.5 can ping 10.0.0.2 but not 192.168.1.100 or 192.168.1.2.

I've checked my firewall logs on both ends, and that is not the problem. Also, the Ubuntu VM has full connectivity to everything else (WAN, other networks at site A, etc). I'm a bit of a newbie to networking, but I'm unable to see anything wrong with Ubuntu's routing table (below) - 172.20.0.1 is the default route, as it should be.

Both Ubuntu machines have `ufw` disabled, and the Proxmox firewall is also disabled.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for troubleshooting this?

```
default via 172.20.0.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens18 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-c9c0c48f2ded proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-2aff47d248c2 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.6 metric 100 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-0a0f137580ce proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-22040c89a1df proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 
172.23.0.0/16 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 linkdown 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-ae49b8c7a0cd proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-af1cc2da36b5 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-f846820847c1 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-c337d629bdd7 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 
172.31.0.0/16 dev br-25edfa50f590 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/20 dev br-cd125e7d0775 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.48.0/20 dev br-d9efec41f6e6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.48.1 
192.168.160.0/20 dev br-8934e4e75f8d proto kernel scope link src 192.168.160.1
```

Comment: Make sure your Ubuntu machine is set up for NAT or Bridged.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how I would go about that. Can you point me to any resources?

Comment: Network mode is set in the VM App

Comment: Oh, I see. I believe it's set up bridged in Proxmox. If it weren't, would I have access to any of my network in Ubuntu? As is, I can access the internet and all of my network except the other site's machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this was necessary or if this was the right way to go about this, but I solved it by manually adding a route:

Site A: `sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.20.0.1`

Site B: `sudo ip route add 172.20.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1`

I just wish I knew why this was necessary on my Ubuntu VMs but none of my other Linux- or BSD-based VMs.

While everything I read insisted that `netplan` was the correct way to make these routes permanent (i.e., persist across reboots), I wasn't able to figure this out. I'm not sure why, but my YAML file was missing a lot of the configuration I thought it should have. So, I just added `@reboot` cron entries like so:
`crontab -e` -> (on a new line at the bottom of the file) `@reboot sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.20.0.1`.

Again, I wish I knew what was going on here, but it works.